# spring boot with websocket and postman

Tags: spring-boot, postman, spring-websocket

I have created test project according to [tutorial](https://www.baeldung.com/websockets-spring)

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WSConfig implements WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry config) {
        config.enableSimpleBroker("/topic");
        config.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
    }

    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
        registry.addEndpoint("/chat");
        registry.addEndpoint("/chat").withSockJS();
    }

@Controller
public class WSController {

    @MessageMapping("/chat")
    @SendTo("/topic/messages")
    public String send(String message) throws Exception {
        return "test";
    }
}
```

I am struggling to connect with postman, I tried different urls:

- ws://localhost:8080
- ws://localhost:8080/app
- ws://localhost:8080/app/chat

each time I click connect button, I get 404 as a response
What am I doing wrong? (I am new to websocket)

Answer (score 6):

I was able to connect to the `ws://localhost:8080/chat` endpoint after following instructions at https://blog.postman.com/postman-supports-websocket-apis/

[image]

Note: I also looked at https://spring.io/guides/gs/messaging-stomp-websocket/ for more information on setting up a SpringBoot WebSocket project.

Comment: omg so the problem was my url, it should be ws://localhost:8080/chat not .../app/chat :) thanks a lot

Comment: happy to help! @rsobies

Comment: Are you able to push messages with this config ? When I try to publish messages to /topic I don't see any messages on postman. when I debug further I found the user is not getting registered in registry.